# Getting Nth item from end of table column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet containing a list of products that are currently in stock:
[image: Product List]

Then I also have a worksheet that contains transactions made on those products which can be of type *SALE* and *PURCHASE*:
[image: Transaction Log]

What I need is to display the last 7 transactions under a product that are of type *SALE*, which means for each *Week X Sales* I need to get the *Nth* item from the transaction log (starting from the last entry):
[image: Sales]

Note: The rows from the above sheet are the same as from the product list (first picture).

I've seen answers to similar questions but could not apply since said answers usually used hardcoded cell addresses instead of table references (`MyTable[MyColumn]`). I'd like to know if this is possible using only a cell formula instead of VBA.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're trying to find the last seven entries for a given **Product Name** that are of **Type** *SALE*, and then return **Quantity** under the applicable **Week** *X* **Sales** column in the second table? How are you going about choosing which **Product Name** to use and how are you determining which week falls under each column in the second table?

Comment: Also, can you please show us which formulas you've happened upon that didn't work for you? That'll help us know where to start.

Comment: @TotsieMae Correct, I need to return the **Quantity** of the last N (in this case 7) entries which are of **Type** *SALE*. As for the **Product Name** each row in the *Week X Sales* table corresponds to the **Product List** table also please ignore the week (Week 1 = Last, Week 2 = Second from Last, etc.). Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was misunderstanding on how the criteria on `IF`s work on Excel, at first I was using it like:

```
=IF(AND(tblTransactions[Product Code]=[@Code], tblTransactions[Type]="SALE", ...)
```

Then I found some posts stating that you need nested `IF`s if you want multiple criteria, the working formula for me now is:

```
=INDEX(tblTransactions[Quantity],LARGE(IF(tblTransactions[Product Code]=[@Code], IF(tblTransactions[Type]="SALE", ROW(tblTransactions[Invoice '#])-ROW(tblTransactions[@[Invoice '#]])+1)),3))
```

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  For other readers with a similar problem, it may be hard to understand how the formula works so they can adapt it to their own situation.  Can you add a short description of what the formula does?  BTW, if you don't receive other solutions that you like even more, you can accept your own answer in another day to indicate that the problem has been solved.